# running dotnet app from a single shared exe file

Tags: c#, .net, share

As far as you know, are there any problems in running a C# application from a shared exe file? This is a request from a customer asking their 20 clients to run the same exe file on shared path.
First tests didn't show problems, but don't know on long terms. I personally don't like this, don't think that framework was developed with this in mind, but they do for a quick upgrade of the exe file when needed.
Any point to discourage this?

Thanks
Sav

Comment: @Saverio - Your question is not clear.  What exactly do you mean by a "shared exe file"?

Comment: In any case, the exe would still run as a process on each user's computer. You might have issues with concurrency, since all users will be sharing any resources that the exe points to.

Answer (score 1):

The first consideration is deployment concerns. Prior to .NET 3.5 SP1, this was not allowed by default because the shipped security policy treated network locations in a less trusted way. .NET 3.5 SP1 and later, [this is no longer the case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx). You could, of course, use caspol to [modify this security policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2007/10/26/adhoc-poll-allowing-net-exes-to-run-off-a-network-share.aspx) to allow this, if you are working with versions of the framework prior to that. Additionally, some more recent versions of Windows [may have additional security policies outside of .NET](https://serverfault.com/questions/226526/is-it-possible-to-restrict-executing-an-exe-on-a-network-drive-with-windows-7) that can prevent execution from remote locations.

The second consideration is making sure the application is designed in a way that it is aware of its environment, not assuming the environment is relative to the local machine when it is expected to be so (which could affect resolution of external resources and, depending on the situation, could result in resource contention or users overwriting each other's data).

The third is availability. What if the server hosting that executable becomes unavailable (is powered off by accident, crashes, experiences networking issues, is renamed, etc.)? Is that acceptable? How large is the executable? If it is large, that can increase network traffic and at any rate result in the executable being slow to start as it is invoked over the network.

I suppose for trivial applications, these issues may be negligible. However, there are lots of ways of installing applications on client computers in a way that they are installed and updated quickly and easily, such as [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We currently run software designed in house.  This runs off a central SQL database.  Each computer is set up with a batch program which runs through Windows Start Up and downloads the current program files from the central server.  The .exe is therefore run off the individuals computer and not off the server.  This has been found, in our case at least, to be the most efficient method.